# Add Columns to Access database with ASP

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I have an website written in ASP classic with VB. I need to add a column to the table, but I cannot take down the website to be able to edit the table in access. How do I do this in code?

I am very new to ASP and access, I have a lot of experience in PHP and MYSQL but I have been able to find the syntax.

Thanks for all assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenDB("database/cpio.mdb")
SQL = "ALTER TABLE Members ADD business_url text"

dbRS1.Open SQL, dbConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

Answer (score 0):

Should be relatively easy if you are already connecting to the database and executing queries. Try:

```
ALTER TABLE <table> ADD COLUMN <column> <type> NULL/NOT NULL
```

Comment: OpenDB("../database/database_name.mdb")
ALTER TABLE Members ADD COLUMN Agency Integer NOT NULL

Is that all i need?

Comment: It looks right to me. Do you have a test environment you can try it out on first? Or, grab a copy of the database and try it with VBScript first.

Comment: I don't have a test environment, and it does not work..
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch: 'OpenDB'

/edit_database.asp, line 3

Comment: Can you post a full example on pastebin?

Comment: got it!

OpenDB("database/cpio.mdb")
SQL = "ALTER TABLE Members ADD business_url text"

dbRS1.Open SQL, dbConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic